# How do I replace the values of a key in Python?

Tags: python, function, key, blackjack

I have this Blackjack game where I am trying to make changes to the function `calculate_hand_value (hand)` and take into account that an Ace can have the value 1 instead of 11 (if the total value is over 21, you want the Ace to count as 1). Can anyone help me?

```
import random

full_deck = {"Two of clubs": 2, "Three of clubs": 3, "Four of clubs": 4, "Five of clubs": 5, "Six of clubs": 6,
             "Seven of clubs": 7, "Eight of clubs": 8, "Nine of clubs": 9, "Ten of clubs": 10,
             "Jack of clubs": 10, "Queen of clubs": 10, "King of clubs": 10, "Ace of clubs": 11,
             "Two of diamonds": 2, "Three of diamonds": 3, "Four of diamonds": 4, "Five of diamonds": 5,
             "Six of diamonds": 6, "Seven of diamonds": 7, "Eight of diamonds": 8, "Nine of diamonds": 9,
             "Ten of diamonds": 10, "Jack of diamonds": 10, "Queen of diamonds": 10, "King of diamonds": 10,
             "Ace of diamonds": 11, "Two of hearts": 2, "Three of hearts": 3, "Four of hearts": 4, "Five of hearts": 5,
             "Six of hearts": 6,"Seven of hearts": 7, "Eight of hearts": 8, "Nine of hearts": 9, "Ten of hearts": 10,
             "Jack of hearts": 10, "Queen of hearts": 10, "King of hearts": 10, "Ace of hearts": 11,
             "Two of spades": 2, "Three of spades": 3, "Four of spades": 4, "Five of spades": 5, "Six of spades": 6,
             "Seven of spades": 7,  "Eight of spades": 8, "Nine of spades": 9, "Ten of spades": 10,
             "Jack of spades": 10, "Queen of spades": 10, "King of spades": 10, "Ace of spades": 11,
             }


def get_new_shuffled_deck():
    deck = list(full_deck.keys())
    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck


def get_card_value(card):
    return full_deck[card]


def calculate_hand_value(hand):
    hand_value = 0

    for card in hand:
        hand_value += get_card_value(card)

    return hand_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for card in hand:
    hand_value += get_card_value(card)

    if hand_value > 21:
        hand_value -= 10

return hand_value
```

Comment: this won't work because you can only subtract 10 if there is an ace in the hand cards.

Comment: I dont play black jack! sorry

Answer (score 1):

you could add a counter for aces and in case of being over 21, you could subtract 10 points for each ace.

```
def calculate_hand_value(hand):
    hand_value = 0
    aces = 0

    for card in hand:
        card_value = get_card_value(card)
        if card_value = 11:
            aces += 1
        hand_value += card_value

    for _ in range(aces):
        if hand_value > 21:
            hand_value -= 10

    return hand_value
```

Comment: When I try your code all my cards values are 0 :/

Comment: I got it to work when I mixed it with @nadapez's code :)

Comment: I just fixed the bug. nice that you were able to fix it yourself.